# Regex to match xml elements without child nodes

Tags: xml, regex

I surprised I can't find this so if someone just closes this down as a duplicate and points me in the right direction that's great BUT

I have xml and sometimes the text node is simple i.e.

```
<text>Sometext</text>
```

And sometimes complex

```
<text in_force_from="20061231" newpara="N">
   <changed-by in_force_from="20140101">PRA 2013/34</changed-by>
   <changed-by in_force_from="20061231">2006/40</changed-by>
    This section applies to:
</text>
```

I want to match **all the simple ones only** (e.g. `<text>Sometext</text>`) so with something like this

```
<text [\S\s]*?>[^<]*?</text>
```

OR maybe

```
<text [\S\s]*?>(?!<)*</text>
```

But it's causing notepad++ to grind to a halt. I suspect it's going past the node and trying to match the next text closing tag even if this is 5000 lines away and not part of that node.

What I want it to do is

1. Find a text tag
2. Has this text tag got other tags in
3. If yes then match
4. If no then don't continue with this match. Go and find the next text tag

It's the 4th step that's causing the problem. Any ideas? Is this even possible in regex? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do this with regular expressions. You'll get it wrong. That's not just because it's difficult, it's because it's theoretically impossible. Regular expressions can only be used to process a class of languages called regular languages, and XML is not in that sense a regular language.

The tool for the job is XPath, and the expression you need is //text[not(*)].

Comment: TBH I've abandoned this approach entirely now. This was for preprocessing before serialisation and I need to get of of this rabbit hole. I'm backing up and using LINQ to XML. But this seems right - though i'm not going to test to confirm. Still - please accept the answer. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Add `s` (DOTALL) modifier to your pattern to make dot to match even a new line character also,

```
/<text\b.*?<\/text>/sg
```

For simple nodes,

```
<text[\S ]*?>.*?<\/text>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/21)

Comment: Thanks for the input - but it need to match the simple nodes only - sorry if that wasn't obvious

Comment: ones without child nodes e.g. <text>some containing text</text>

Comment: Thansk - that seems to work in your tester but not notepad++ A variant without the . doesn't do it either <text[\S\s]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/text>

Comment: don't add `\s` to your regex. It matches newline character also. See my update.